# MySQL - limit from two connected tables

Tags: mysql

2 tables:

```
name  
id | title
```

and

```
content  
name | title
```

One name has several contents. name.id ~ content.name

I need to get 3 names with all theirs content.

```
SELECT name.title, content.title
FROM name LEFT JOIN content ON name.id = content.name
LIMIT 3
```

result in 3 contents, not names

Is it possible to do this with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name.title, content.title, content.name
FROM name LEFT JOIN content ON name.id = content.name
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Also, you need to use an `alias` because you are selecting two `title` fields:

```
SELECT (name.title) as name_title, content.title, content.name
FROM name LEFT JOIN content ON name.id = content.name
LIMIT 0, 3
```

**Update:**

I think you need only the `name` field as far as i could figure out from your comment, try this:

```
SELECT content.name
FROM name LEFT JOIN content ON name.id = content.name
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: problem is that i dont know how many results should i get. I need 3 names, but they can contain from 3 up to ∞ contents

Comment: @Qiao: this should return three rows and there by three names because you have already set up `LIMIT 0, 3` which will return only three rows.

Comment: It will return 3 rows of content, but I need to get 3 names.

Comment: @Sarfraz, I think Qiao wants possibly many rows (more than 3), but limited to only 3 distinct `name.id`s

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT content.name, content.title
FROM name LEFT JOIN content ON name.id = content.name
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Subquery?

```
SELECT name.title, content.title
FROM name LEFT JOIN content ON name.id = content.name
WHERE name.id IN (SELECT name.id FROM name LIMIT 3)
```